# Error checking in my application

Tags: cordova, sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2

1.) I have a code script to check if the user has entered a correct email format;

```
if (val.search("[a-z]+@[a-z]+[.][a-z]+") == -1)
                          Ext.Msg.alert("Error", "Invalid e-mail address!!");
```

This code is incorrect as the username and domain name could take in `Numbers` as well. So how do i correct the code ?

2.) In the view, i have 2 fields; password and retype password. How do i check if these 2 are equal ?

```
{
                          xtype:'textfield',
                          name:'password',
                          label:'Password'
                          },
                          {
                          xtype:'textfield',
                          name:'rpassword',
                          label:'retype password'
                          }
                          ]
                   },
                   {
                   xtype:'button',
                   id:'pwdButton',
                   text:'register',
                   ui:'confirm'
}
```

3.) Is there a possibility to do Ajaxified error checking, meaning to pop up error messages as the user goes to the next field (without having to wait till he clicks the `Register` button)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. For performing the `email` validation, you can check out my below code. It also works out, if the `username` and `domain name` have `Numbers`.

   ```
   {
     xtype: 'emailfield',
     name: 'email',
     label: 'Email',
     id: 'emailId',
     placeHolder: 'google@gmail.com',
     required: true,
     listeners: {
       blur: function(thisTxt, eventObj) {
               var emailValue = thisTxt.getValue();
               var atpos = emailValue.indexOf("@");
               var dotpos = emailValue.lastIndexOf(".");
               if (atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>= emailValue.length) {
                   Ext.Msg.alert("Not a valid e-mail address");
               } else {
                   Ext.Msg.alert('Valid','You entered a valid email address');
               }
       }
      }
    }
   ```
2. For checking if user retyped the same password correctly, you can check out the below code,'

   ```
    {
       xtype:'textfield',
       name:'password',
       id: 'pswd1',
       label:'Password'
    },
    {
       xtype:'textfield',
       name:'rpassword',
       id: 'pswd2',
       label:'retype password',
       listeners : {
           blur : function() {
              var prevPassword = Ext.getCmp('pswd1').getValue();
              var rePassword = Ext.getCmp('pswd2').getValue();
              if(prevPassword == rePassword) {
                   Ext.Msg.alert('Success','Passwords match');
              } else {
                   Ext.Msg.alert('Failed','Passwords entered do not match');
                   Ext.getCmp('pswd2').focus();
              }
          }
      }
    }
   ```
3. *meaning to pop up error messages as the user goes to the next field (without having to wait till he clicks the Register button)*

You need to listen for the [blur](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.field.Input-method-blur) event of any form field. So, when that p'cular field looses `focus`, it will call the `blur()` function and then you can perform the validation w/o having to hit the `Register` button.

```
listeners : {
     blur : function() {
         // Validation code goes here .
         ....
         ....
     }
}
```